# find the maximum of a function with bounds in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, max

I would like to find a local maximum of a function f(x) where x can range between two fixed values since f(x) would tend to +inf if x tends to +inf. I've been trying to use such algorithms as `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b`and `scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc` (from scipy.ref guide) but I can't figure out how to correctly set the bounds. (I know, it must be something stupid but I'm quite a noob with Python). Let's give an easy example:

```
>>>import scipy.optimize as opt  
>>>import scipy  
>>>from numpy import *  

>>>def f (x): return x**(1/2.0)  
>>>max_x = opt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(lambda x: -f(x), [0,0], bounds=([0,0],[9,0])) #I want x to range between 0 and 9 and fmax be 3
```

The output is pretty strange, though: I get nothing at all! Not even an error! What am I missing?

Comment: What does `>>> max_x` <enter> say?

Comment: Note that `max_x` will be a 3-tuple as per the docs... The 3rd element will also give some information as to progress

Comment: Try Newton's method on the function's derivative several times to find critical points on the function.  One of those critical points should be the maximum.  This assumes that the function is sufficiently well-behaved.

Comment: Surely the function `-sqrt(x)` has no local maxima?

Comment: Your function is 1-dimensional, but you're trying to use 2-d initial guess and bounds. That's suspicious.

Comment: @Eric Well, you're right: the first derivative of -sqrt(x) never happens to be zero. But what I'm trying to obtain is the maximum value that f(x) can assume in a certain range of x. Am I taking the wrong approach to the matter?

Comment: @MikeMüller Well, it's only a way to call the function opt.fmin and then make Python print it. I could've written anything else, instead. Have I understood your comment correctly?

Comment: I just wanted to see the result, i.e. the value of `max_x`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. However, the result was the "NO FEASIBLE SOLUTION" as pointed out by the answer below. `(array([ 0.,  0.]), array(0.0), {'warnflag': 2, 'nit': 0, 'task': b'ERROR: NO FEASIBLE SOLUTION', 'funcalls': 0, 'grad': array([ 0.,  0.])})` Anyway, now it's fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounds argument goes [(lower1,upper1),(lower2,upper2)], not [(lower1,lower2),(upper1,upper2)].  If you look at your result (max_x) you will see "ERROR: NO FEASIBLE SOLUTION", which I am guessing is because your bounds specify an empty set.

Here is a correct way to call the function.  I assume the square root is just an example.  I used -x**2 instead.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy
from numpy import *
def f(x):
    print x
    return -x**(2)

max_x = opt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(lambda x: -f(x), 1.0, bounds=[(-9,9)],approx_grad=True)
```

Because you are not specifying a gradient function, you need to set approx_grad=True.  The 1.0 is my initial guess for the maximum (although it is obviously zero for this example).  I added a print statement so I can see each time the function is called, but that's normally not necessary.  For more details on different ways to call fmin_l_bfgs_b, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html).

The above code results in:

```
[ 1.]
[ 1.]
[ 1.00000001]
[-0.99999999]
[-0.99999999]
[-0.99999998]
[ 0.001]
[ 0.001]
[ 0.00100001]
[ -5.01108742e-09]
[ -5.01108742e-09]
[  4.98891258e-09]
```

And max_x looks like this:

```
(array([ -5.01108742e-09]),
 array([  2.51109971e-17]),
 {'funcalls': 4,
  'grad': array([ -2.21748344e-11]),
  'task': 'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL',
  'warnflag': 0})
```

Comment: Well, it's great! Your code is working perfectly! Actually, I was a bit doubtful about the bounds argument, I thought I had tried all the combinations between those values but it looks as if I hadn't! Just one last question: how can I use separately the fmin value I get among the max_x results? I mean, I would like to use fmin for other calculations: let's say, multiply it by two (in your example still zero, though). Can I do that?

Comment: The returned value is a standard Python data structure called a tuple, which is similar to a list except that it's immutable.  If you look at the link in my answer, under "returns" you'll see three labelled objects, x, f, and d.  These correspond to the three items in the returned tuple.  You can access the first one, labelled "x" in the linked doc, as max_x[0].  Note that it is a numpy array and not a simple float.  You can get at the elements of a numpy array in the same way.  For example, max_x[0][0] is the first element in your (potentially multivariate) optimal point.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using multivariate minimizers? Try `scipy.optimize.fminbound`.

```
max_x = opt.fminbound(lambda x: -f(x), 0, 9)
```

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know this particular function! (scipy.optimize.fminbound) However, it works as well: I'll keep that in mind for quick evaluations of min/max, thanks!